# Booting Ubuntu 20.04 from USB on a Raspberry Pi 4 with new bootloader

Tags: 20.04

I am trying to boot my RPI 4 from USB without using a SD card.
I am able to boot Raspberry OS after updating to the latest firmware/bootloader but I'm not able to figure out what to do to get ubuntu to boot.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if normal "plain" Ubuntu works on the RaspberryPi 4. I assume that you'll need a special `arm` version that's also optimized for the Pi. According to the [official Raspberry Pi Downloads page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/), Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Core and Ubuntu Server are supported. You might want to try one of these images!

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have tried both versions of 20.04 that is included in the Raspberry pi imager & non will boot. i changed the UUID & got a boot screen but would not load the OS.

Answer (score 0):

To boot Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1 beta 2 from USB on a Raspberry Pi 4 with new bootloader, I followed this link: [RPI4 Direct USB Boot](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=278791)

1. Upgrade RPi4 to the latest [RPi EEPROM firmware](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/boot-raspberry-pi-4-usb).
2. Operate on another working Ubuntu PC:

- Flash USB to the latest **Ubuntu Mate** image, for example, [ubuntu-mate-20.04.1-beta2-desktop-arm64+raspi.img.xz](https://releases.ubuntu-mate.org/focal/arm64/ubuntu-mate-20.04.1-beta2-desktop-arm64+raspi.img.xz)
- Mount the USB to this Ubuntu PC, there will be two partitions appear (from now on, **your-name** refer to your particular pathname):

  ```
  /media/your-name/system-boot
  /media/your-name/writable
  ```
- Issue the following commands:

  `cd /media/your-name/system-boot
  zcat vmlinuz > vmlinux`
- Modify **/media/your-name/system-boot/config.txt** [pi] section to:

  ```
  [pi4]
  max_framebuffers=2
  dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
  boot_delay
  kernel=vmlinux
  initramfs initrd.img followkernel
  ```
- Create **/media/your-name/writable/boot/firmware/auto_decompress_kernel** and make executable `sudo chmod +x auto_decompress_kernel`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -e

#Set Variables
BTPATH=/boot/firmware
CKPATH=$BTPATH/vmlinuz
DKPATH=$BTPATH/vmlinux

#Check if compression needs to be done.
if [ -e $BTPATH/check.md5 ]; then
    if md5sum --status --ignore-missing -c $BTPATH/check.md5; then
    echo -e "\e[32mFiles have not changed, Decompression not needed\e[0m"
    exit 0
    else echo -e "\e[31mHash failed, kernel will be compressed\e[0m"
    fi
fi

#Backup the old decompressed kernel
mv $DKPATH $DKPATH.bak

if [ ! $? == 0 ]; then
    echo -e "\e[31mDECOMPRESSED KERNEL BACKUP FAILED!\e[0m"
    exit 1
else    echo -e "\e[32mDecompressed kernel backup was successful\e[0m"
fi

#Decompress the new kernel
echo "Decompressing kernel: "$CKPATH".............."

zcat $CKPATH > $DKPATH

if [ ! $? == 0 ]; then
    echo -e "\e[31mKERNEL FAILED TO DECOMPRESS!\e[0m"
    exit 1
else
    echo -e "\e[32mKernel Decompressed Succesfully\e[0m"
fi

#Hash the new kernel for checking
md5sum $CKPATH $DKPATH > $BTPATH/check.md5

if [ ! $? == 0 ]; then
    echo -e "\e[31mMD5 GENERATION FAILED!\e[0m"
    else echo -e "\e[32mMD5 generated Succesfully\e[0m"
fi

#Exit
exit 0
```

- Create **/media/your-name/writable/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/999_decompress_rpi_kernel** and make executable `sudo chmod +x 999_decompress_rpi_kernel`:

```bash
DPkg::Post-Invoke {"/bin/bash /boot/firmware/auto_decompress_kernel"; };
```

- Unmount USB and boot USB from RPi4 to install **Ubuntu Mate**. Might need to reboot Ubuntu Mate installation procedure twice to pass the rainbow screen if it get stuck.

---

Comment: not sure what I did wrong. My boot is stuck at post rainbow screen with message: initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
spi-bcm2835 fe204000.spi : could not get clk: -517

Comment: actually stuck at splash screen shown ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Did you upgrade RPi 4 (not other model) to the latest EEPROM firmware, step 1?

Comment: Yes. The boot starts from USB, the splash screen comes up. But its stuck there with error ".debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: Read-only file system"

Comment: There is a report for how to fix "stuck with error ".debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: Read-only file system"":

[quote=dreamlax007 post_id=1742554 time=1602772266 user_id=350849] Got it fixed. For some reason balenaEtcher creates writable partition with no room for temp and vars. I resized the partitions after the flash and now able to boot into Mate from USB :). [/quote]

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=131&t=278791&p=1742977#p1742977